# How to set the accessibility label in asset catalog? Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiaccessibility, asset-catalog

Is there any way to set the `accessibilityLabel` for an image asset inside the asset cataloge? I don't want to handle that label everywhere I use that image asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to set the `accessibilityLabel` for an image asset inside the asset catalog?

The `.xcassets` is definitely **not done for this purpose**.

However, you can **create a new UIView** including the image you're using everywhere so as to define the `accessibilityLabel` in it once for all.

You use this new `UIView` in place of the image coming from your asset catalog and you **don't have to handle that label everywhere**.